# Fiz um joguinho bem simples em Python mas ele entra em um loop infinito, alguém, por favor poderia me ajudar nessa?

Tags: python

```
                       #jogo do adivinha#

resp = 1
i = 5
x = 0
print ("Tente adivinhar o Número que eu estou pensando.")
print ("Você só tem 5 chances e o número está entre 0 e 100.")
while resp != 0:

    print ("")
    try:
        a=raw_input("tentativa %d: " %i)
        a= int (a)
    except:
        a = ''
        print ("Digite um número inteiro válido.")

    if a!='':
        while a!=x and i<5:
            if a==x:
                break

            elif a<x:
                print ("o numero é mais alto(+)")
                print ("")

            elif a>x and a!='':
                print ("o numero é mais baixo(-)")
                print ("")

            if a!='':
                i=i+1

            try:
                a=raw_input("tentativa %d: " % i)
                a= int(a)
            except:
                a = ''
                print ("Digite um número inteiro válido.")
                print ("")

    if i==5 and a!=x:
        print ("")
        print ("suas chances acabaram você perdeu!!!")
        print ("o número era', x")
        print ("")

    else:
        print ("")
        print ("Você acertou. Parabens!!!", a)
        print ("")

    resp=raw_input("Para jogar denovo aperte 1 - para sair aperte 0: ")
```

Comment: Tente colocar um else no while com `exit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema do loop encontra-se no fato de você estar utilizando a função `raw_input` para atribuir o valor à variável `resp` e estar comparando esse valor com um inteiro.

Caso o usuário digite `0`, o valor que é armazenado em `resp` é `"0"` (uma string contendo o caractere `0`).

Para resolver o problema do loop infinito, basta substituir a linha 6 por:

```
while resp != "0":
```

---

Algumas considerações a respeito do seu código:

- Tente ser homogêneo nos espaçamentos e seguir um padrão. Tente usar `a = int(a)`, ao invés de `a= int (a)`. Boas práticas são encontradas nas `Python Enhancement Proposal` (PEP). Sugiro que leia, pelo menos, a PEP 8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/.
- Na linha 29 você faz uma verificação desnecessária. Para que o programa chegue ali, é garantido (vide linha 16) que `a != ''`.